# How do I filter output conditionally in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Let's say for example that I want to run:

```
brew upgrade scala
```

If the current version of `scala` is installed then it fails with the error:

```
Error: scala 2.12.8 already installed
```

Now I could get rid of all the errors using:

```
brew upgrade scala 2>/dev/null
```

I would like to only hide the output when it contains "already installed". This ought to be an option in brew but doesn't exist. It is still an interesting problem regardless.

So how do I filter output conditionally in bash?

Comment: Do you want filtering line by line? In this case use grep: `brew upgrade scala 2>&1 | grep -v 'already installed'`.

Comment: @gudok that should be an answer.

Comment: Line by line filtering would work in this particular case. The issue with @gudok's answer is that now other errors will not be on std err any more.

Comment: Without redirecting stderr to stdout it's not possible, I mean you can redirect stderr to grep like `brew upgrade scala 2> >(grep -Fv 'already installed')` but that will mess up the order of output.